# Haskell fromInteger function negative exponent

Tags: haskell

I'm new with Haskell, and I'm trying to define a function `eAprox :: Integer -> Float` with recursion. The function is the next [summation of 1/(k!) with k from 0 to inf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlRI9.png)

And what I got so far is

```
eaprox :: Integer -> Float

eaprox n | n == 0 = 1

         | n > 0 = fromInteger ((factorial n)^(-1)) + eaprox (n-1)
```

Haskell accepts this, but with any number (except 0) it gives me the message *** Exception: Negative exponent.** I changed the (^) for (^^) or (**), but then I can't even load the function.. I'm guessing there's a mistake with the fromInteger function because I don't quite understand how it works.. Any thoughts?

Comment: `1/(k!)` is not an integer anyway. So even if you had your exponent, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Factorial produces a positive integer, and the reciprocal `^(-1)` of that (once past 1) is a fraction from 0 to 1; never an integer. So you need to perform the conversion before you take the reciprocal, something like:

```
factorial n = product [1..n]

eaprox n = sum [recip . fromInteger . factorial $ x | x <- [0..n]]
```

With this version, `eaprox 17` is approximately equal to `exp 1`.

Comment: You were right! I convert the factorial first and it worked! Thank you very much! I changed the last line:         n > 0 = (fromInteger (factorial n))^^(-1) + eaprox (n-1)